# Must a comma be used after the word "similarly?"

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Which sentence is correct?

In graphic design, I consider the use of color. **Similarly in photography**, I also consider...

In graphic design, I consider the use of color. **Similarly, in photography**, I also consider...

I know that there's usually a comma after "similarly" but the sentence in the second sentence sounds too long and has too many pauses. I prefer the first option because it flows better, but is it grammatically correct? If not, is there a way to write that sentence in a way that flows better?

Comment: I would use a comma after *similarly* and not before *I consider* in any of the sentences,   including 'In graphic design I consider the use of color'.

Comment: It is hard to know if the second sentence sounds too long, because you haven't given us the entire second sentence.  I'd put a comma after similarly, but I don't know what I would do after photography because I don't know what the sentence says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of similarly at the beginning of a sentence requires a comma, because it is a sentence adverb (see http://theeditorsblog.net/2016/02/21/a-tale-of-adverbs-and-the-comma/) that modifies the entire sentence rather than the word that follows.

If you want to add more variety, you will need to rearrange one or both sentences. I'd offer suggestions, but I'm not sure of your context/meaning.